# Do I need node_modules folder on live host server if I'm using webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

To be clear, I am **not** asking if I need node_modules folder on live host server. That question & answer exists on Stack Overflow already. The consensus answer, in general is YES - I still need the node_modules directory during runtime.

I am also **not** asking about running npm init or npm install. I understand how that works.

I am specifically asking - **do I still need the node_modules directory on the live/host server if I use webpack during my build process**? Doesn't webpack bundle all the necessary JS, etc into folder? Can I delete the node_modules folder if use webpack? Or, will I still need that directory during runtime?

This is for a basic front end, client side web application only. This front end calls other API only for backend sevice. This front end web application is being hosted on Windows/IIS.

The site's published code includes static references like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css?id=f243e9c6546d420fec1f">
<script src="/js/app.js?id=bf7be8f179cc272c0190"></script>
```

Ignore the id= part, as I think that's part of the web framework for cache busting.

Comment: How are you using the bundle?  Is it a static resource that will run on a static hosting server or are you running something like an express app?  Webpack bundles all the resources for a static bundle.  In other words your client side resources are bundled, but if your application isn't a separated front/back end node application, you *may* still need the `node_modules` directory.  Can you explain your setup a little more?

Comment: @zero298 Thank you. The application is referencing the bundled JS and CSS only. I've updated the question to include that this is basic front end web application only that runs on Windows/IIS. I wonder if the code in that bundled JS file needs/references code in the node_modules folder. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be doubly sure, could you add your `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: @zero298 I can't add the webpack.config.js. I am actually using Laravel's wrapper for webpack called Mix (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix). It uses a completely different configuration file. But for simplicity sake for this question, I chose to just say webpack.

Comment: node_modules is only read from by javascript executed by nodejs (including the webpack command line tool itself, which is run with node). If you aren't running node on your server, you don't need node_modules. static files are never served directly from node_modules

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, everything is in the bundle after you build.  You can take the files defined as [output](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/) (usually whatever is in the "dist" folder) and stick them on whatever static server you want without the need of the supporting `node_modules`.

Answer (score 5):

During your web pack build process ,need the node modules folder , because when you import a file from the node_modules , web pack will try to fetch the file from the particular node_module folder recursively.

Once you successfully done with the build you will get a dist package folder with  all the bundles for the deployment, it will not contain node_modules folders.

You can test it by using

```
npm run build
```